# How do I stop a variable from being dropped at end of scope when it's used by another function?

Tags: rust, lua

I'm trying to throw the parsing of a piece of Lua code into a function to make it easier. Right now, i have the following code:

```rs
fn load_file<'lua, 'a>(
    context: Context<'lua>,
    root: &'a str,
    project_filename: &'a str,
) -> Chunk<'lua, 'a> {
    let path_str = Path::new(root).join(project_filename);
    let source = std::fs::read(path_str).expect(&format!(
        "Failed to load project file: {}",
        project_filename
    ));

    let chunk = context
        .load(&source)
        .set_name(project_filename)
        .expect("Failed to create chunk");

    return chunk;
}
```

`source` is dropped at the end of the function, however chunk, which is returned, needs it. I can't just clone it, since that's dropped too. How do I keep the reference alive past the lifetime of the function?

Comment: What are `Context` and `Chunk` they are not in the `lua` crate...

Comment: This looks like [`rlua`](https://docs.rs/rlua/latest/rlua/struct.Chunk.html) code (or `mlua`, which is a fork of that crate that has diverged somewhat). Would be helpful to include that info in the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: You can't (short of manually leaking the memory). Your function will have to return `source`, so that ownership can transfer to the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a `Chunk` does not parse or compile the source code - this is why it borrows from `source`, as it will need access to that data later on.

If you want to compile the chunk without also running it (removing the dependency on keeping the source around), you can call the [`into_function`](https://docs.rs/rlua/latest/rlua/struct.Chunk.html#method.into_function) method.

If you're happy to execute the chunk at the same time that you compile it, then use either [`call`](https://docs.rs/rlua/latest/rlua/struct.Chunk.html#method.call), [`eval`](https://docs.rs/rlua/latest/rlua/struct.Chunk.html#method.eval) or [`exec`](https://docs.rs/rlua/latest/rlua/struct.Chunk.html#method.exec).

The above links point at `rlua`'s docs, but the same answer applies if you're using `mlua`.